# Rails:How can I get these check_boxes and radio buttons to show the data from the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, checkbox, formhelper

Here is some code that is used basically to show a table of listings from my database. Last few columns are nothing but radio buttons and check boxes that are tied to specific boolean attributes of the model. Ive programmed the check boxes and radio buttons. But How do I get them to display the values in the database?

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listings</h1>

<table class="datatable">
 <tr id="heading" >
  <th >id</th>
  <th >name</th>
  <th>telephone</th>
 </tr>

<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <tr id="body">
    <th><%=listing.id%></th>
    <th><%= link_to listing.name, edit_listing_path(listing) %></th>
    <th><%=listing.telephone%></th>

 <%= form_for listing do |f| %>     
 <td id="keep"><%= f.radio_button :keep, "Keep" %></br>
    <%= f.label :keep, "Keep" %>
 </td>
 <td id="delete"> <%= f.radio_button :keep, "Delete" %></br>
    <%= f.label :keep, "Delete" %>
 </td>
 <td id="checked"><%= f.check_box :checked %></br>
    <%= f.label :checked, "checked" %>
 </td>
 <td id="collected"><%= f.check_box :collected %></br>
    <%= f.label :collected, "collected" %>
 </td>
 <td id="digitized"><%= f.check_box digitized %></br>
    <%= f.label :digitized, "digitized" %>
 </td>
 <td id="in_db"><%= f.check_box :in_database  %></br>
    <%= f.label :database, "database" %>
 </td>
    <td id="submit"><%= f.submit "update" %></br>

  </td>
  <% end %>
   </tr>
 <% end %> 
 </table>
```

Also the reason Im choosing the "form" here is because eventually after I figure out how to show the data here, Id like to have this view also "update" the data in the model if the user changes any values in the checkboxes. But, Ill get to that once Ive learnt how to display the model's values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :keep, "Keep", :checked => listing.keep %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Im just curious, where in the documentation is this given. I looked at the rails guides and api.rails.. I couldn't find this!

Comment: i didn't find it either, but apparently all rails tags that generate html tags have the capability to add options. the checked option is the html tag option of the radio button. same with :value for text fields

Comment: Strange. I find that when googleing for rails questions, either one gets outdated version answers or a whole bunch of questions on how to do complex stuff. But its hard to find a simple succint answer to a straightforward question. Wondering if its me or if anyone else feels like that. Seems like more documentation is needed....